# iOS disable "select more photos" alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm developing an app on react native and I faced a problem with limited iOS photo permission.

I'm using this library – https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll to fetch photos and I have a question about native ios code.

When I set `limited` permission then every time when I launch the app on a screen that fetches photos iOS shows me an alert.

**I would like to disable this alert and never show it** although I can't find what exactly triggers it

This is a source code of a function that I use -> https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll/blob/1421c1d7e4a384e3a37c42a4907738ae4fe9e399/ios/RNCCameraRollManager.m#L244

I beleive that this function triggers the alert because when I comment out it the alert does not show up, maybe I'm wrong though coz I don't have any expereince in objective-c

[image: alert]

P.S. I've tried to modify [this function](https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll/blob/1421c1d7e4a384e3a37c42a4907738ae4fe9e399/ios/RNCCameraRollManager.m#L101) but looks like it has nothing in common with the alert ;(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To disable the automatic prompt when the user has granted limited photo access you need to add [`PHPhotoLibraryPreventAutomaticLimitedAccessAlert`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrary/3616113-presentlimitedlibrarypicker) to your info.plist